# LibGDX How can I add value on already existing value?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a game and when you complete a level you earn 25 gold. What I want is that it can stack so if I play again and earn 25 gold I'll now have 50 gold. I have this but I can't stack, the game only remember the 25 gold from the current game:

```
public static void addgold(int value){
    gold += value;
    gLabel.setText(String.format("%01d", gold));

    prefs.getInteger("gold", 0);
    prefs.putInteger("goldCoin", gold);
    prefs.flush();
}
```

I think I should write something like:

```
goldCoin + gold
```

goldCoin is what I have earned in total and gold is what I get from the current game.

,

Here is all of the code:

```
public class Hud2 implements Disposable {
private Hud2 hud;
public Stage stage;
private boolean timeUp;
private Viewport viewport;

private Integer worldTimer;
private float timeCount;
private static Integer score;
private static Integer gold;

private boolean keyPressed = false;
private Runner player;
private static RunningGame game;

private TweenManager tweenManager;
public Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;



private static Label scoreLabel;
private static Label timeLabel;
private static Label gLabel;
private Label levelLabel;
private Label worldLabel;
private Label runLabel;
private Label countdownLabel;
private Label objectiveLabel;


private static int hScore;
private static int gCoin;
private static Preferences prefs;



public Hud2(SpriteBatch sb) {
    worldTimer = 10;
    timeCount = 0;
    score = 0;
    gold = 0;





    viewport = new FitViewport(RunningGame.V_WIDTH, RunningGame.V_HEIGHT, new OrthographicCamera());
    stage = new Stage(viewport, sb);

    Table table = new Table();
    table.top();
    table.setFillParent(true);




    prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("PreferenceName");
    hScore = prefs.getInteger("highScore", 0);
    //prefs.putInteger("highScore", 0);

    prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("PreferenceGold");
    gCoin = prefs.getInteger("goldCoin", 0);
    //prefs.putInteger("goldCoin", 0);

    countdownLabel = new Label(String.format("%01d", worldTimer), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.WHITE));
    scoreLabel = new Label((String.format("%01d", score)), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.WHITE));
    gLabel = new Label((String.format("%01d", gCoin)), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.WHITE));
    timeLabel = new Label((String.format("%01d", hScore)), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.WHITE));
    levelLabel = new Label("", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.WHITE));
    worldLabel = new Label("Level 2", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.WHITE));
    runLabel = new Label("You won!", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.RED));
    objectiveLabel = new Label("Objective: 60", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.WHITE));



    table.add(worldLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
    table.add(gLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
    table.add(countdownLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
    table.row();
    table.add(timeLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
    table.add(levelLabel).expandX();
    table.row();
    table.add(timeLabel).expandX();
    table.add(scoreLabel).expandX();
    table.add(objectiveLabel).expandX().padTop(10);


    stage.addActor(table);
}




public void update(float dt) {
    if (score < 1) {
        return;
    }
    timeCount += dt;
    if (timeCount >= 1) {
        if (worldTimer > 0) {
            worldTimer--;
        } else {
            timeUp = true;
        }
        countdownLabel.setText(String.format("%03d", worldTimer));
        timeCount = 0;





        }

        Table table = new Table();
        table.top();
        table.setFillParent(true);
    if (worldTimer == 0)
        if (score >= 60) {
            Hud2.addgold(25);
            table.add(runLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new com.mygdx.game.Level2.WinScreen2(game));
            stage.addActor(table);






        }

            else if (score <= 59)
                ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new com.mygdx.game.Level2.GameOverScreen2(game));


    }


public static void addscore(int value){
    score += value;
    scoreLabel.setText(String.format("%01d", score));

    prefs.getInteger("score", 0);
    if (score > hScore) {
        prefs.putInteger("highScore", score);
    }
    prefs.flush();
}

public static void addgold(int value){
    gold += value;
    gLabel.setText(String.format("%01d", gold));

    prefs.getInteger("gold", 0);

    prefs.putInteger("goldCoin", gold);
    prefs.flush();
}
```

Comment: gold is 0 and when you complete a level you get 25 gold.

Comment: You need to show us more of your code. You have merely provided the code behind one method of your program. Show the whole class, and if it is too much, remove all unnecessary methods and fields.

Comment: Some members are static and some are not. This is highly confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have two variables for gold:

`private static Integer gold;`

`private static int gCoin;`

Your `addGold()` method updates `gold` but never gCoin yet your preferences gets the value of `gCoin` from `gCoin = prefs.getInteger("goldCoin", 0);`

Answer (score 0):

`gold` is static, meaning that instances of `Hud2` do not have their own `gold` variable. Every time you create an instance of `Hud2`, you set `gold` to `0` because you have written:

```
public Hud2(SpriteBatch sb) {
    [...]
    gold = 0;
    [...]
}
```

I do not know how you have written your code, but it all looks incredibly... fishy. You are mixing static and non-static fields and methods like crazy. To be honest you should probably rewrite the whole class, but if you want a fast fix, my guess is that you can simply remove `gold = 0` from the constructor and instead initialize it when you declare it instead. Like this:

`private static Integer gold = 0;`